# Just get back the value from a mongoose query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the value from articlePrice only. But also get the attribute name. How do I fix that?

```
//Search Articles
export const searchArticels = async (req, res) => {

const maxPrice = await Articel.find()
.sort({ articelPrice: -1 })
.limit(1)
.select("articelPrice -_id");


const minPrice = await Articel.find()
.sort({ articelPrice: 1 })
.limit(1)
.select("articelPrice -_id");

  console.log("MAX: " + maxPrice);
  console.log("MIN: " + minPrice);
};
```

> MAX: { articelPrice: 560.5 }
> MIN: { articelPrice: 230 }

Answer (score 0):

Uou can seperate those like this :

```
//Search Articles
export const searchArticels = async (req, res) => {

const maxPriceDoc = await Articel.find()
.sort({ articelPrice: -1 })
.limit(1)
.select("articelPrice -_id");

const minPriceDoc = await Articel.find()
.sort({ articelPrice: 1 })
.limit(1)
.select("articelPrice -_id");

const maxPrice = maxPriceDoc[0].articelPrice;
const minPrice = minPriceDoc[0].articelPrice;

console.log("MAX: " + maxPrice);
console.log("MIN: " + minPrice);
};
```